# .htaccess. 404 RewriteRule with same file name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new here!

First of all, sorry if my English is bad!

I am making a simple RewriteRule and it is giving me a 404. 
I have to say that it works in commercial hostings (like 1and1), but not in my Apache (Ubuntu Server)

If the RewriteRule has the same name of the php file it returns 404.

- RewriteRule #1 is working.
- RewriteRule #2 is NOT work (404)
- RewriteRule #3 works
- RewriteRule #4 works

  ```
          Options +FollowSymlinks
          RewriteEngine On

          RewriteBase /
          RedirectMatch ^/es/$ /es/home
          RewriteBase /es/

          #1
          RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L,NC]
          #2
          RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L,NC]
          #3
          RewriteRule ^anyName$ login.php [L,NC]
          #4
          RewriteRule ^singup$ register.php [L,NC]
  ```

Comment: you mean it is not working for login keyword meanwhile it is working for anyname on same login.php page.

Comment: Yes, if the name is the same name of the php file it returns 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have folders with the same name, but it is solved adding

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
```

or try this rule if you are removing .php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

above will remove .php from all file having .php extension